# Matching values in Excel

Tags: excel, match, vlookup

I have two tables in this form:

| Name | Function1 |
| --- | --- |
| A | 3 |
| B | 4 |
| C | 20 |
| E | 5 |

| Name | Function2 |
| --- | --- |
| A | 6 |
| B | 8 |
| C | 2 |
| D | 25 |

And I would like to create table look like this:

| Name | Function1 | Function2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 3 | 6 |
| B | 4 | 8 |
| C | 20 | 2 |
| D | - | 25 |
| E | 5 | - |

How can I pair those values and creates this type of table?

Comment: Search for "excel merge two tables by column"

Comment: You can use `VLOOKUP()`, `INDEX/MATCH`, `XLOOKUP()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If those functions are numbers, as in your example, you can use **Consolidate**:

> [Consolidate
> data](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/consolidate-data-in-multiple-worksheets-007ce8f4-2fae-4fea-9ee5-a0b2c9e36d9b)

As quick example, I consolidated both tables in 1 single table activating options *top row* and *left column*:

[image]